# xsd schema choice for legacy unknown values

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm trying to come up with a schema that allows xml to specify that an element is unknown for legacy reasons rather than just making the element non mandatory.

For instance:

```
<personName>John</personName>
```

is valid but

```
<personName></personName>
```

is not valid but

```
<personName><legacyUnknown /></personName>
```

is valid.

And this should work regardless of the complexity of the element personName. Sometimes it might be a simpletype with a string restriction, other times it might be a complex element.

```
<choice>
    <element name="personName" type="name" />
    <element name="personName" type="legacyUnknown" />
</choice>
<simpleType name="name">
<restriction base="string">
...enum values
</restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Would be great but as far as I'm aware you can't do this. I know it could be done with a substitutiongroup but it seems to me like I would have to put the verbose code for building a sub group on every type that I want this to apply to.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Schema is about enforcing restrictions.  Who do you want to force to send the personName? Who doesn't have to send it?  (see my solution if this the answers are client and server)

Answer (score 1):

You could decide to attach the "legacy unknown" semantics to the otherwise rather useless xsi:nil construct. Then you would define the element in the schema as nillable, and label the instance with xsi:nil="true" to capture the meaning you intend with "legacy unknown".

Answer (score 0):

If the restriction should be applied depending on the context of the document (like client request vs. server response), you could consider the following:

```
 <xs:element name="request">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="personName" type="PersonName"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="response">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="personName" type="PersonName"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="PersonName">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```